# Withdrawn phantom votes in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

After giving an vote to an answer today on the latest iOS update, I decided to withdraw it (forgive me). Inadvertently, I stumbled upon an interesting vote-count related bug.

When a vote is cast, it's indicated by its blue vote arrow, and rightfully, when it's withdrawn, the blue highlight should be removed. The answer *should* have zero votes after I retracted my vote. However, after retracting my vote, the blue highlight remains:

> [image]

Retracting this phantom vote results in a -1 score for the answer even though I upvoted it from 0, and an error:

> [image]

The addition and retraction of the vote were performed seconds apart.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.  Are there more steps involved?  When you cast a vote, the UI updates instantly, then updates again with the successful response from the server (or reverts on an error).  I'm not sure where the failure would have occurred.

Comment: There aren't any more steps involved, so I suspect it might've been a client-sees-object-that-isn't-on-server-and-sends-a-conflicting-action sort of glitch to which the server responds with an error similar to what I saw